# Backup with only ssh

Tags: magento-1.8, backup

I have install an extension, it totally kill my magento, which stay on 503 error. I have try to clean cache, delete maintenance.flag and use ssh to uninstall the extension, but it's still in 503, so I would try to backup my Magento.

I have, in /var/www/magento.xxx.com/var/backup a 1407765060_snapshot.tgz, taking ~155Mo, how can I use it, with ssh lines, to perform backup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it's of code, then you can extract it with help of following command (in current directory):

```
tar -zxvf /var/www/magento.xxx.com/var/backup/1407765060_snapshot.tgz
```

Also, you should have DB dump which can be deployed into mysql server with help of command:

```
mysql -uUSER -p -hHOST DB_NAME < db_dump.sql
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank's a lot !

Answer (score 2):

First off you can easily disable the bad extension and probably fix your site by navigating within your root Magento directory and go to `app/etc/modules/` and find the files for your extension (usually look like `Company_ExtName.xml`) and simply rename the `.xml` file to something else like `.xml.off` then flush the Magento caches. That will essentially "remove" the extension so that Magento ignores the extension files.

If you still need to restore the old backup I would first suggest taking a new backup excluding the media/ directory as that contains all product and other images and can increase backup size significantly. Here are the full details taken from this post on [how to backup Magento](http://www.snapfast.com/blog/magento-backup-methods/).

```
tar -zcf --exclude=media/ backup-YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM.tar.gz public_html/
```

Run that command in SSH and be sure to replace YYYY MM DD HH MM with the proper time. Also if your site doesn't use `public_html/` like most cPanel systems do, you might have to change it to `www/` or something else to match your site's file structure.

After you have a backup then to restore the old backup you'll need to take a few steps.

1. Move current files and extract the contents of your old backup into your web directory
2. Assuming you have a db backup you'll want to create a new database and restore the old db backup there
3. Because you've restored to a new database, you'll need to update Magento's local.xml to reflect the new database details
4. Flush Magento caches

**1. Move Current Files & Restore Backup Files**

```
mv /var/www/magento.xxx.com/ /var/www/magento.xxx.com-backup/
mkdir /var/www/magento.xxx.com/
cd /var/www/magento.xxx.com/
tar -zxvf /var/www/magento.xxx.com/var/backup/1407765060_snapshot.tgz
```

Those commands will move your current site into a `-backup` folder for safe keeping. Next it will re-create the `magento.xxx.com/` folder and then extract the contents of your backup to that folder.

**2. Restore old Database**

You could delete all the contents of your current database then restore the backup in it's place, but I like to restore it to a new database just to keep your old one for safe keeping.

Assuming the `.sql` dump file is gzipped (`.sql.gz`) first we'll need to extract it:

```
gzip -d /var/www/magento.xxx.com/sqldumpfile.sql.gz
```

Make sure you have already created a new database and user with permissions then we can restore the old database backup to the newly created database:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p DB_NAME < sqldumpfile.sql
```

Depending on the size of your database that could take a while. If you're familiar with something like `screen` I recommending running it in screen so your SSH session doesn't die mid-import.

**3. Update Magento's local.xml**

Now that your files are restored and your database contents are restored, you'll want to update the `local.xml` file to reflect the new database name, username, and password. You need to edit `app/etc/local.xml` either using vi, nano, or FTP or something. Find the proper pieces and replace the database username, password, and database name:

```
<host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host> 
<username><![CDATA[db_user]]></username>
<password><![CDATA[db_password]]></password> 
<dbname><![CDATA[db_name]]></dbname>
```

**4. Flush Caches**

Now that everything has been restored we should flush the caches to avoid any issues:

```
rm -rf /var/www/magento.xxx.com/var/cache
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with ssh, log into your server, rename your old document root `public_html` (depends on OS) into something like `public_htmlOLD`, create a new doc. root `public_html`, copy your backup to the new `public_html`, unzip and untar, change file permission if necessary and try to reload your magento store through your browser again.